# Ion search bar not filtering when typing on device

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an ionic 3 application with angular 5 and I'm facing a strange issue. I have a modal with a ion-searchbar and a ion-list of ~ 250 items. I'm using the same filter event as in the ionic doc demo of the search bar.

In the browser it works perfectly but once it's on the phone, on ionic run Android/ios, the list doesn't refresh until I close the keyboard or touch anywhere else on the screen (causing the keyboard to close too), instead of filtering when typing.

HTML file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Choix du pays</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_item">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio [value]="item.alpha3" (ionSelect)="selectedItem(item)"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngIf="!data?.length">
      <h2>Aucun résultat</h2>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and type sript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-choose-country',
  templateUrl: 'choose-country.html',
})
export class ChooseCountryPage {
  data;
  items: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.data = this.navParams.get('data');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setItems();
  }

  setItems() {
    this.items = this.data;
  }

  filterItems(ev: any) {
    this.setItems();

    let val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
  selectedItem(item) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
  }
}
```

Have you got any ideas ?
Tank you internet!

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your code? html and component? what function for filtering do you use?

Comment: I've added code extract :) thx !

Comment: Hi @NikoLP, I think you just need to use some fully supported (by mobiles) event instead of oniput(). onchange, for example, could do the trick for you in this case.